# For-loop doesn't work

Tags: infinite-loop

I need some help. I try to run the code below, but at the end `I1 = 0, I2 = 0` (the same as their initial values). I'm not sure which part of my code is wrong.

```
Q = 1415; μ = 1000; σ = 500;
double dx;
double x;
double fx;
double fxplusdx;
double I1;
double I2;
I1 = 0;
I2 = 0;
For[x = 0, x <= Q - dx, dx += 0.01,
  fx = 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x] - μ)/σ];
  fxplusdx = 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x + dx] - μ)/σ];
  I1 = I1 + 0.5*(x*fx + (x + dx)*fxplusdx)*dx;
  I2 = I2 + 0.5*(fx + fxplusdx)*dx]
I1
I2
```

Comment: It's hard to know where to start. "double" is not a mathematica command. Your For syntax is wrong (you use x=0 but then try to increment another variable dx, which is itself uninitialized).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mma.SE! To make the most of the site start by **taking the [tour] now**. Please read the documentation and write your code in actual Wolfram Mathematica Language. After you have done your due diligence, if you still have problems then  [edit] your question and share your code.

Comment: Your question will be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it's [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake of syntax error and is unlikely to help any future visitors as it's easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Answer (score 6):

First of all there is nothing like `double` in Mathematica, you don't need to define the type of variable here.

I don't know what problem are you trying to solve, since you don't describe it, but I at least can point out absolute wrong parts of your code.

There is such a thing in Mathematica, called function, so you can parametrize, instead of hard-coding:

```
foo[Q_, μ_, σ_] := Module[{xxx},...]
```

With the body the code should look like:

```
foo[Q_, μ_, σ_] := Module[
  {dx, x, fx, fxplusdx, I1 = 0, I2 = 0},

  For[x = 0, x <= Q-dx, dx += 0.01,
   fx = PDF[
     NormalDistribution[0, 
      1], (InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], 
         x] - μ)/σ];

   fxplusdx = 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 
      1], (InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], 
         x + dx] - μ)/σ];

   I1 = I1 + 0.5*(x*fx + (x + dx)*fxplusdx)*dx;

   I2 = I2 + 0.5*(fx + fxplusdx)*dx
   ];

  {I1, I2}
  ]
```

Besides not knowing what do you want to achieve here, I see following problems:

1. `dx` has to have initial value, if you want to use it in `For[]`
2. You have to be sure that you want to do ~150.000 iterations.